# Would like to average quantiles over dataset

Tags: average

I have a set of data that for each I calculate the 25,50,75 quantiles.

I have approx, 400 of these measurements. Can I average the 400 quantiles? Any theory advice would be helpful!

Comment: What kind of data?  What format?  Which programming language?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: each of the 400  measurements are observations. For each set of observations I have calculated the 25, 50 and 65 quantiles. My questions is can I theoretically average all the 400 quantiles to get an average. I know how to code everything up and more of a theory question.

Comment: Statistically, that's not guaranteed.  Consider the two sets (1,2,3,4,5..10) and (100,200,300,400,...1000).  The 50th percentile of the first is 5, of the second is 500.  The average would be 202 but the combined 50th percentile is 100.  If the data is randomly distributed you'd be close, but not exact.